# Add popup menu to AppBarButton

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to add a contextual menu to a button from the appBar(bottom appBar). My min SDK is Windows 8.0. I would like something like this popup from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj150602.aspx):

[image: msdn-popup-menu]

Unfortunately I cannot use `MenuFlyout` since it is available only from Windows 8.1+, so I want to achieve this menu in another way. If you know how it can be done, please tell me.

Below is my bottom bar:

```xml
<common:LayoutAwarePage.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0" DataContext="{Binding}">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource EditAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="EditQuote_Click"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource RemoveAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="RemoveQuote_Click"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource AddAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="AddQuote_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource HelpAppBarButtonStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at the [Callisto](http://timheuer.github.io/callisto/) library on Nuget. It's built by Tim Heuer who's one of the guys working on the xaml team at Microsoft and fills in some of the gaps in the 8.0 control set. It includes a Menu Flyout control that looks not that coincidentally like the controls added in 8.1.

The samples app in the project includes an example of what you're looking for (a Menu Flyout from an App Bar).

Edit: If you're targeting Windows 8.1 with your project then the Menu Flyout control is now built into the platform.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the Flyout Settings sample at:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Settings-Flyout-eceaafea

Or if you are targeting Windows 8.1, flyouts have become much easier, check the `MenuFlyout` element:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182878.aspx#menuflyout

Comment: OK, I'm targeting win 8.0 so the first link should be followed in my case. I'm wandering if I can set this flyout just above my appBarButton? To appear like a real flyout element...